# Making data points transition smoothly?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to make a time series move smoothly like my x-axis. Essentially, I continuously update an array of fixed length with a new random measurement (i.e. add one, delete one) each 200 milliseconds. Here is my original code:

```js
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////// Set-up  /////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const margin = {
  left: 80,
  right: 80,
  top: 30,
  bottom: 165
};

//Actual graph smaller than svg container 
var width = $('#chart').width() - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = $('#chart').height() - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const yDomain = [0, 70];
const yTickValues = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70];

const TIME_INTERVAL = 200;

//xAxis domain-> 10 seconds 
const originalTime1 = "1970-01-01T00:00:00",
  originalTime2 = "1970-01-01T00:00:10";

//Get the milliseconds since UNIX epoch 
var date1 = new Date(originalTime1).getTime(),
  date2 = new Date(originalTime2).getTime();

//Random measurements
var measurements = [];

//Equally spaced time measurements within millisecond interval
var arraySize = Math.floor(Math.abs(date2 - date1) / TIME_INTERVAL);

//Random measurements 
var trueValue = 25;
var accuracyValue = 45;
var precisionValue = 25;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////// SVG //////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

const svg = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

const g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////// Axes & Scales ////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var xAxisGroup = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x-axis");

var yAxisGroup = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y-axis");

//Dynamic
var xScale = d3.scaleTime();

//Fixed
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([yDomain[0], yDomain[1]])
  .range([height - margin.bottom, 0]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .ticks(d3.timeSecond.every(1))
  .tickSizeInner(15)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%M:%S"));

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale)
  .tickValues(yTickValues)
  .tickFormat(d3.format(".0f"));

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////// Functions //////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function draw() {

  //Transition parameters 
  t = d3.transition()
    .duration(TIME_INTERVAL)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear);

  //Update xAxis scale
  xScale.domain([date1, date2])
    .range([0, width]);

  //Call axes
  xAxisGroup.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")")
    .transition(t)
    .call(xAxis);

  yAxisGroup.call(yAxis);

  //DATA JOIN
  var circles = g.selectAll("circle").data(measurements);

  //EXIT
  circles.exit().remove();

  //UPDATE
  //Update DOM elements on the screen with smooth linear transition
  circles
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return xScale(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return yScale(d[1]);
    });

  //ENTER
  circles.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "enter")
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("r", "4")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return xScale(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return yScale(d[1]);
    });

  //Update dates & random array for next iteration 

  date1 += TIME_INTERVAL;
  date2 += TIME_INTERVAL;

  measurements.push(addNewMeasurement());
  measurements.shift();

};

function initializeRandomArray() {

  for (i = 1; i <= arraySize; i++) {

    var temp = [];

    temp[0] = date1;

    //Math.random not exactly 1 -> but VERY CLOSE
    var precision = (Math.random() * 2 * precisionValue) - precisionValue;
    temp[1] = accuracyValue + precision;

    //Add new element at the end of the array
    measurements.push(temp);

    date1 += TIME_INTERVAL;
  }

  //Reset back date1 
  date1 = new Date(originalTime1).getTime();
};

function addNewMeasurement() {
  var temp = [];

  temp[0] = date2;

  var precision = (Math.random() * 2 * precisionValue) - precisionValue;
  temp[1] = accuracyValue + precision;

  return temp;
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////// Main /////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

initializeRandomArray();
draw();

d3.interval(function() {
  draw();
}, TIME_INTERVAL);
```

```css
.x-axis,
.y-axis {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  stroke-width: 0.06em;
}

#chart {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

The problem is when I apply the transition *t* to my data points, I get:

```js
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////// Set-up  /////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const margin = {
  left: 80,
  right: 80,
  top: 30,
  bottom: 165
};

//Actual graph smaller than svg container 
var width = $('#chart').width() - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = $('#chart').height() - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const yDomain = [0, 70];
const yTickValues = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70];

const TIME_INTERVAL = 200;

//xAxis domain-> 10 seconds 
const originalTime1 = "1970-01-01T00:00:00",
  originalTime2 = "1970-01-01T00:00:10";

//Get the milliseconds since UNIX epoch 
var date1 = new Date(originalTime1).getTime(),
  date2 = new Date(originalTime2).getTime();

//Random measurements
var measurements = [];

//Equally spaced time measurements within millisecond interval
var arraySize = Math.floor(Math.abs(date2 - date1) / TIME_INTERVAL);

//Random measurements 
var trueValue = 25;
var accuracyValue = 45;
var precisionValue = 25;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////// SVG //////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

const svg = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

const g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////// Axes & Scales ////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var xAxisGroup = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x-axis");

var yAxisGroup = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y-axis");

//Dynamic
var xScale = d3.scaleTime();

//Fixed
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([yDomain[0], yDomain[1]])
  .range([height - margin.bottom, 0]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .ticks(d3.timeSecond.every(1))
  .tickSizeInner(15)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%M:%S"));

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale)
  .tickValues(yTickValues)
  .tickFormat(d3.format(".0f"));

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////// Functions //////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function draw() {

  //Transition parameters 
  t = d3.transition()
    .duration(TIME_INTERVAL)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear);

  //Update xAxis scale
  xScale.domain([date1, date2])
    .range([0, width]);

  //Call axes
  xAxisGroup.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")")
    .transition(t)
    .call(xAxis);

  yAxisGroup.call(yAxis);

  //DATA JOIN
  var circles = g.selectAll("circle").data(measurements);

  //EXIT
  circles.exit().remove();

  //UPDATE
  circles
    .transition(t)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return xScale(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return yScale(d[1]);
    });

  //ENTER
  circles.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "enter")
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("r", "4")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return xScale(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return yScale(d[1]);
    });

  //Update dates & random array for next iteration 
  date1 += TIME_INTERVAL;
  date2 += TIME_INTERVAL;

  measurements.push(addNewMeasurement());
  measurements.shift();

};

function initializeRandomArray() {

  for (i = 1; i <= arraySize; i++) {

    var temp = [];

    temp[0] = date1;

    //Math.random not exactly 1 -> but VERY CLOSE
    var precision = (Math.random() * 2 * precisionValue) - precisionValue;
    temp[1] = accuracyValue + precision;

    //Add new element at the end of the array
    measurements.push(temp);

    date1 += TIME_INTERVAL;
  }

  //Reset back date1 
  date1 = new Date(originalTime1).getTime();
};

function addNewMeasurement() {
  var temp = [];

  temp[0] = date2;

  var precision = (Math.random() * 2 * precisionValue) - precisionValue;
  temp[1] = accuracyValue + precision;

  return temp;
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////// Main /////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

initializeRandomArray();
draw();

d3.interval(function() {
  draw();
}, TIME_INTERVAL);
```

```css
.x-axis,
.y-axis {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  stroke-width: 0.06em;
}

#chart {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Is there a simple way of making the data points move horizontally smoothly? Thank you very much for your input!

Comment: Bostock covers this issue here,  [Path Transitions](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/)

Comment: @SmokeyShakers Thank you very much!! That is very helpful! :)